# DataBinding: is there any way to restrict the type of the integer of ObservableInt, @ColorInt or @ColorRes

Tags: android, binding

When we use Android DataBinding library, we always write something like this:

```
// layout xml
android:textColor="@{vm.textColor}"

// SomeVm.kt
var textColor = ObservableInt()
...
textColor.set(R.color.some_color)
```

But this is wrong. TextView.setTextColor() requires a @ColorInt int parameter like:

```
public void setTextColor(@ColorInt int color);
```

But what we set is a @ColorRes int resource.

So my question is, is there any way to restrict the `textColor` variable to be a @ColorInt observable int only?

I've tried:

```
var textColor = ObservableField<@ColorInt Int>()
```

But the code does not give an error:

```
textColor.set(R.color.some_color)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's about restricting but about giving the `setTextColor` method the right parameter type.

Have you tried doing `textColor.set(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.some_color))` instead so that you get a `@ColorInt`? That should work.

Otherwise create your own `BindingAdapter` such as:

```
@BindingAdapter("textColor")
fun setTextColor(view: TextView, @ColorRes color: Int) = with(view) {
    textColor = ContextCompat.getColor(context, color)
}
```

And use it in your layout like `app:textColor="@{vm.textColor}"`